# Android-x86 8.1: graphical glitches

Tags: android-x86, 8.1-oreo, graphics

I can install android-x86-8.1-rc1.iso, but when I boot it looks like this:
[image: Booting]
[image: Setup Wizard]

What can i do to fix this?

PS: I installed it directly to my Root-Server.
Virtualization is activated and already works with VirtualBox and similar programs.

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar (less severe) issues in `cm-x86 14.1` and this is how I solved it:

1. Wait for the glitches to start.
2. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> to go to the terminal.
3. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> again to go back the the Android GUI.

After that, Android should look normal.

Comment: Tried that too.
Also Tried to change screen resolution with Gear lock but no effect